# JdbcTempate.query(sqlString) is getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: sql-server, jdbctemplate

I am new to spring-3.2.5; when i tried to fire a query with JdbcTemplate class that statement is getting stuck in infinite loop.
Same code is working on another machine so code is not the problem.

Please help me and let me know what could be the possible root cause of getting into infinite loop on JdbcTemplate.query(sql).

even i tried with simple JDBC connection and tried to execute Statment.executeQyery(sql), still the same behavior observed.

Means its the issue with my machine or some configurations regarding executing query to db.

DB - SQL Server - i am able to execute Query in DB directly.

Please help.

Comment: with simple Jdbc code; i am able to make connection to DB but not able to fire Query